# How to generate a Swagger file for a REST API URL

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, informatica, informatica-cloud

My requirement is to generate a Swagger File for a given ReST API URL. I have invoked the URLs using POSTMAN client and it was working fine.

However, for this URL to use in Informatica cloud, it's required to have associated Swagger file either json or yaml format.

could you please guide how we can do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to generate Swagger.json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48764682/113116)

Comment: Thanks Helen.It was useful